# Rails Rswag Swagger UI Not Sending Headers Properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, openapi, rswag

I'm using gem rswag for documentation for my Rails API. My rails API requires that all requests include `headers['Content-Type']='my-fancy-content-type'` and `headers['Accept']='my-fancy-accept`. So far I've done testing using POSTMAN and all are working fine. My Rspec tests also all pass.

When using the swagger UI at `http://localhost:3002/api-docs/index.html`. I input the correct param (just id in this case), and the correct headers as shown in the screenshot:

[swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTJAA.png)

It seems that none of the headers were sent. The console shows it was doing `curl -X GET "http://localhost:3002/segments/122" -H "accept: */*"` without any headers.

I set up my `spec/swagger_helper.rb` like:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.swagger_root = Rails.root.join('swagger').to_s
  config.swagger_docs = {
    'v1/swagger.yml' => {
      openapi: '3.0.1',
      info: {
        title: 'API V1',
        version: 'v1'
      },
      paths: {},
      servers: [
        {
          url: 'http://{defaultHost}',
          variables: {
            defaultHost: {
              default: "localhost:#{ENV['PORT']}"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  config.swagger_format = :yaml
end
```

My swagger.yaml looks like:

```
---
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: API V1
  version: v1
paths:
  "/segments/{id}":
    get:
      summary: Find segment by id
      tags:
      - Segments
      parameters:
      - name: Accept
        in: header
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: Content-Type
        in: header
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: integer
      responses:
        '200':
          description: success
          content: {}
        '404':
          description: not_found
          content: {}
servers:
- url: http://{defaultHost}
  variables:
    defaultHost:
      default: localhost:3002
securityDefinitions:
  Content-Type:
    type: string
    description: Content-Type
    name: Content-Type
    in: header
```

A snippet of a test used to generate the swagger documentation is(it passes normally):

```
path '/segments/{id}' do
    get 'Find segment by id' do
      tags 'Segments'
      parameter name: :Accept, in: :header, type: :string, required: true
      parameter name: 'Content-Type', in: :header, type: :string, required: true
      parameter name: :id, in: :path, type: :integer
      context 'when record exists' do
        response '200', :success do
          schema type: :object,
                 properties: {
                   content: {
                     id: {type: :string},
                     type: {type: :string},
                     attributes: {
                       id: :integer,
                       ...
                     }
                   }
                 }
          run_test! do |response|
            expect(response.status).to eq(200)
            
          end
        end
```

I tried adding `c.swagger_headers = { 'Content-Type' => 'my-fancy-content-type', 'Accept' => 'my-fancy-accept' }` inside Rswag::Api.config inside `config/initializers/rswag_api.rb` but it did not work (i.e. not sending any of the headers).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Paste your YAML file into https://editor.swagger.io, fix the errors and warnings, then try again. Does this help resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

In my `spec/swagger_helper.rb`, I no longer use Open API but I use Swagger 2.0. So change

```
config.swagger_docs = {
    'v1/swagger.yml' => {
      openapi: '3.0.1',
```

to

```
  config.swagger_docs = {
    'v1/swagger.json' => {
      swagger: '2.0',
```

And now it works.